# Javascript on change function loads site new

Tags: javascript, input, onchange

Hello I am kind of new to Javascript, I did write a function that adds a new input field to a webpage, but when the button is pressed the sites get new loaded and changes from before are gone. I want the new create fields to be with the new input and the old inputfields should be able also with new text if the button is pressed again. It seems like if the button is clicked the site is loaded new, how can I prevent this.

```
<div id="Attibutes">
    <label style="padding-left:5px"><b> Attributename</b></label><label style="padding-left:8px"><b>Attributwerte getrennt mit;</b></label><br>
    <!-- Attribute Namen bearbeiten -->      
    <%int numberAttributes = (Integer) request.getAttribute("numberAttributes");
    int count = numberAttributes;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberAttributes; i++ ) {%>
    <input type="text" onchange="showTable()" id="AttributeName<%=i%>" name="AttributeName<%=i%>" value="<%= request.getAttribute("attributeName"+ i)%>">
    <!-- Attrribute Zeilen bearbeiten -->        
    <input type="text" onchange="showTable()" id="AttributeLine<%=i%>" name="AttributeLine<%=i%>" value="<%= request.getAttribute("attributeLine"+ i)%>">
    <input type=button onchange="showTable()" id="ButtonDelete<%=i%>" value="Zeile löschen" onclick="removeLine(<%=i%>)">
    <br id="br<%=i%>">
   <% }%>
   </div>
```

Here my javascript function:

```
<input style="margin-left: 12px" type=button value="Zeile hinzufügen" onclick="add()">
            <script>
            function add() {
                counter++;
                var element = document.getElementById("Attibutes");
                var content = "";
                content += '<input type="text" onchange="showTable()" name="AttributeName' + counter + '" id="AttributeName' + counter + '" value="">';
                content += '<input style="margin-left: 6px" type="text" onchange="showTable()" name="AttributeLine' + counter + '"id="AttributeLine' + counter + '" value="">';
                content += '<input style="margin-left: 6px" type=button onchange="showTable()" name="AttributeName' + counter + '"id="ButtonDelete' + counter + '" value="Zeile löschen" onclick="removeLine(' + counter + ')">';
                content += '<br id="br' + counter + '">';
                element.innerHTML += content;
            }
```

I've been checking the internet, but could not find why the site is loading again. Thanks for you're help.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Your code is neither complete nor minimal.

Comment: That's what the buttons do, they submit a form, when they are placed in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `e.preventDefault()` to function click. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @Halyna's answer - the reason this is happening is that a [form submission](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) is actually happening. This is the default behaviour of the `button` element, or an `input` tag that has the property `type="submit"` or `type="button"`.

If you want to stop that from happening, you should update your code to look something like:

```
<input style="margin-left: 12px" type=button value="Zeile hinzufügen" onclick="add(this)" />

function add(e) {
            counter++;
            var element = document.getElementById("Attibutes");
            var content = "";
            content += '<input type="text" onchange="showTable()" name="AttributeName' + counter + '" id="AttributeName' + counter + '" value="">';
            content += '<input style="margin-left: 6px" type="text" onchange="showTable()" name="AttributeLine' + counter + '"id="AttributeLine' + counter + '" value="">';
            content += '<input style="margin-left: 6px" type=button onchange="showTable()" name="AttributeName' + counter + '"id="ButtonDelete' + counter + '" value="Zeile löschen" onclick="removeLine(' + counter + ')">';
            content += '<br id="br' + counter + '">';
            element.innerHTML += content;
            e.preventDefault()
        }
```